# syntax error while passing arguments to function through std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote the code in the following way, when i compile with  `c++ -std=c++0x -lpthread` the program its giving compilation errors. i checked for the problem many times but can not solve.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
#define ATOM 200000
#define WATER 10000
#define POLAR 20000
int main() {

        char text[ATOM][30];
        int now=0;
        int noh=0, na=0;
        int nop=0, lines=0;
        char inputfile[30];
        char p[30];
        string pdbdata;
    cout<<"enter input file"<<endl;
        cin>>inputfile;
    char pdbn[10000][100];
        char pdb[100];
    float x, y ,z;
        FILE *inputf=fopen(inputfile,"r");
        char c;
        int i;
    int c1 = 0;
    if(inputf == NULL) {
                cout<<"cannot open inputfile";
                return 0;
        }
    while (1) {
                if( fscanf(inputf, "%s", pdb) == EOF ) {
                        fclose(inputf);
                        break;
                } else {
                        strcpy(pdbn[lines],pdb);
            lines++;
                }
                if(lines == 0)
                        return 0;
                na = 0;
                now = 0;
                nop = 0;
                noh = 0;
                FILE *pdbf = fopen (pdb, "r");
                float a, b;
                if (pdbf == NULL)
                        return 1;
                while (1) {
                        if ((c=fgetc(pdbf)) != EOF) {
                                p[0] = c;
                                for(i=1; i<30; i++)
                                        p[i] = fgetc(pdbf);
                                p[30] = '\0';
                                pdbdata = p;
                                c1++;
                                fscanf (pdbf, "%f%f%f%f%f\n", &x, &y, &z, &a, &b);
                                size_t f = pdbdata.find ("ATOM");
                                if(f!=std::string::npos) {
                                        strcpy(text[na],p);
                                        na++;
                                        f=pdbdata.find("WAT");
                                        if((f!=std::string::npos)&&(p[13]=='O')) {
                                                now++;
                                        } else if((p[13]=='O') || (p[13]=='N')) {
                                                nop++;
                                        }
                                        if((p[12]=='H') || (p[13] == 'H'))
                                                noh=noh+1;
                                }
                        } else {
                                fclose(pdbf);
                                break;
                        }
                }

        }
    float X[na * lines], Y[na * lines], Z[na * lines];
    int pol[lines * nop];
    int wat[lines * now];
    int fsw[lines * now];
    int na1, now1, nop1;
        inputf = fopen(inputfile,"r");
    int m = 1;
    int SnumCPU = sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN );
    thread tr1[SnumCPU];
    int nfiles = lines/(SnumCPU - 1);
        for (i = 0; i < (SnumCPU - 1); i++) {
                int in = i * nfiles;
                tr1[i] = thread(readfile1, in, nfiles, &pdbn[0], &X[0], &Y[0], &Z[0], &wat[0], &pol[0], now, nop, na, &text[0]);
        }
        if ( lines % (SnumCPU - 1) != 0)
                tr1[(SnumCPU - 1)] = thread(readfile1, (SnumCPU - 1) * nfiles, (lines % (SnumCPU - 1)), &pdbn[0], &X[0], &Y[0], &Z[0], &wat[0], &pol[0], now, nop, na, &text[0] );
        for (i = 0; i < (SnumCPU - 1); i++) {
                tr1[i].join();
        }
        if ( lines % (SnumCPU - 1) != 0)
                tr1[SnumCPU - 1].join();
    return 0;
}
```

and the `readfile1` function defined as follows

```
void readfile1 (int istart, int iend, char *pdbn[100], float *X, float *Y, float *Z, int *wat, int *pol, int now, int nop, int na, char *text[30]) {
    float x, y, z, a, b;
    for(int i = istart; i< istart + iend; i++) {
                string pdbdata;
                char p[40];
        int na1 = 0;
                int now1 = 0;
                int nop1 = 0;
                FILE *pdbf=fopen(pdbn[i],"r");
                int pdbid = na * i;
        int watid = i * now;
        int polid = i * nop;
        float a, b;
                if(pdbf == NULL)
                        break;
        char c;
                while (1) {
                        if((c = fgetc(pdbf))!=EOF) {
                                p[0] = c;
                                for(i = 1; i < 30; i++)
                                p[i] = fgetc (pdbf);
                                p[29] = '\0';
                                pdbdata = p;
                                fscanf(pdbf, "%f%f%f%f%f\n", &x, &y, &z, &a, &b);
                                size_t f;
                                strcpy (text[na], p);
                                X[pdbid + na1] = x;
                                Y[pdbid + na1] = y;
                                Z[pdbid + na1] = z;
                                f = pdbdata.find("WAT");
                                if ((f != std::string::npos) && (p[13] == 'O')) {
                                    wat[watid + now1] = na1;
                                        now1++;
                                } else if((p[13] == 'O') || (p[13] == 'N')) {
                                    pol[polid + nop1] = na1;
                                        nop1++;
                                }
                na1++;
                        } else {
                            fclose (pdbf);
                                break;
            }
                }

    }
}
```

giving errors as follows

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/functional:70,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/thread:39,
                 from parallel3.cpp:8:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/tr1_impl/functional: In member function ‘typename std::result_of<_Functor(typename std::result_of<std::_Mu<_Bound_args, std::is_bind_expression::value, (std::is_placeholder::value > 0)>(_Bound_args, std::tuple<_UElements ...>)>::type ...)>::type std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::__call(const std::tuple<_UElements ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes ...>) [with _Args = , int ..._Indexes = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, _Functor = void (*)(int, int, char**, float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, int, int, int, char**), _Bound_args = int, int, char (*)[100], float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, int, int, int, char (*)[30]]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/tr1_impl/functional:1191:   instantiated from ‘typename std::result_of<_Functor(typename std::result_of<std::_Mu<_Bound_args, std::is_bind_expression::value, (std::is_placeholder::value > 0)>(_Bound_args, std::tuple<_UElements ...>)>::type ...)>::type std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args& ...) [with _Args = , _Functor = void (*)(int, int, char**, float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, int, int, int, char**), _Bound_args = int, int, char (*)[100], float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, int, int, int, char (*)[30]]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/thread:114:   instantiated from ‘void std::thread::_Impl<_Callable>::_M_run() [with _Callable = std::_Bind<void (*(int, int, char (*)[100], float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, int, int, int, char (*)[30]))(int, int, char**, float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, int, int, int, char**)>]’
parallel3.cpp:150:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/tr1_impl/functional:1137: error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[100]’ to ‘char**’ in argument passing
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/tr1_impl/functional:1137: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'
```

Comment: You should seriously think about reducing this down to a short self-contained example that reproduces the problem. I am sure most of the code shown here is irrelevant.

Comment: We don't even know what error your compiler is generating...

Comment: In its current form the question has no place here. Voted to put on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `text` is an array of arrays, not an array of pointers. So Change the function signature to make the char parameters `char (*pdbn)[100]` and `char (*text)[30]`, or equivalently, to `char pdbn[][100]` and `char text[][30]`.

(To be clear: each element of `text` is a `char[30]`, and *not* a `char *`.)